# How to convert a column of years to a default date

Tags: pandas

Given a column of years:

```
Years
2016
2015
2015
2017
2016
```

How would I convert those years into dates that default to January 1:

```
Years
2016-01-01
2015-01-01
2015-01-01
2017-01-01
2016-01-01
```

I'm pretty new to programming and my brain hurts from trying to think of a solution. I think I need to write some sort of function to convert the years.

```
def convert_years(year):
    return converted_year
```

I know this is a poor effort but I don't know what to do. I've been searching on Stack Overflow for a couple of hours with no progress. Thanks

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(d['Years'],format='%Y')` ?

Comment: Interesting enough, you may also do `pd.to_datetime(df['Years'].astype(str))`

Answer (score 0):

You can create the date using `datetime.date` from the year.

```
import datetime
df['Years'] = df['Years'].apply(lambda x: datetime.date(int(x), 1, 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like this:

```
df['Years']= pd.to_datetime(df['Years'], format='%Y')
```

It fills the column with the native pandas (numpy) datatype `datetime64`.

**Edit:** If your column contains other values, that are not interpretable as valid year numbers, I would suggest to add another column with the converted date to leave the original value untouched. You can do this as follows:

```
# create a new column and initialize it as datetime
df['date']= pd.Series(dtype='datetime64[ns]')

# setup an indexer that identifies the valid year values
# here I assume column Years contains strings and 
# as an example only want to consider strings to be valid years
# if the string consists of exactly 4 digits and is between
# 1980 and 2050
indexer= df['Years'].str.match('^[0-9]{4}$') & (df['Years']>'1980') & (df['Years']<'2050')

# now set the new date column for all rows with a valid year in
# Years to that date (all others remain as NaT
df.loc[indexer, 'date']= pd.to_datetime(df.loc[indexer, 'Years'], format='%Y')
```

Comment: Thanks @jottbe. What if a row contains something that can't be datetime formatted? For example:
    `Years
    2015
    2015
    6 months`

How do I just skip over the '6 months' entry.

Comment: Does your column contain strings? In such a case I would not suggest to store the dates in the original columns, but create a new one. I add a proposal in the post above.